# i want to use aes encrytion in my custom storage cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I have AES encrypt cordova plugin in my app, and custom native storage plugin. How to use AES encrypt plugin in my existing storage plugin.

Comment: What use case do you plan to cover? prevent smartphone owner from looking into its own data(wtf)? prevent thief to get his hands on cached data(good but...)? Where do you plan to store key (I hope it is not a key which is hardcoded into code)? What will prevent thief from getting the key via API from server and how owner could report to the server the theft of his smartphone to invalidate the key?

Answer (score 1):

First install https://github.com/Ideas2IT/cordova-aes256

those

```
ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-aes256-encryption

cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-add-swift-support --save
```

then encrept Your data

```
declare var mycordova: any;


   mySecureKey: String = '12345678910123456789012345678901'; // Any string, the length should be 32
   mySecureIV: String = '1234567891123456'; // Any string, the length should be 16
```

then encript see documentation as wee

```
 let data = "test";
 encrypt(this.mySecureKey, this.mySecureIV, data);
```

then store it

```
var storage = window.localStorage;
var value = storage.getItem(key); // Pass a key name to get its value.
storage.setItem(key, your_data) // Pass a key name and its value to add or update
```